# How do I delete people from the friend list?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

How can I delete people from my friends list? I have been researching for days, but haven't been able to find the answer.

Answer (score 7):

To remove a friend from your friends list, open the Social window by pressing <kbd>O</kbd>:

[image: Cropped screenshot of the Social window]

Then right click on your friend and select the "Remove" option from the menu. This will remove the person from your friends list.

**Note**: your friends list in WoW is actually your Battle.net friends list, removing a friend from within WoW will also remove them from within Starcraft 2 and Diablo 3.